# KineticJS group.get('#id')[0] is being inconsistent in my code

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, get, kineticjs

I have created a class in my program which uses KineticJS for the "view" part of my MVC design. One of the instance variables in the class is a group which holds multiple rectangular objects. My problem arises when I try to select a specific rectangle in that group by its ID.

I use this.backgroundGroup.get('#id')[0] with no problem in my subMeasure prototype function, but when I try to use it in my drawMeasures prototype function, it stops my canvas from drawing anything. The console in Chrome says "cannot read properties "ids" of undefined".

The only difference between these to uses of the get method is that the subMeasure function is called on the "click" event, and the drawMeasures function is called when View is instantiated.

```
function View(){
    this.status = 0;
    this.stage;
    //layers
    this.backgroundLayer;
    this.lineLayer;
    this.noteLayer;
    this.scanLayer;
    this.editLayer;
    this.UILayer;
    //groups
    this.backgroundGroup;
    //edit buttons
    this.subMeas;
    this.addMeas;
    this.edit;

    this.backgroundArray;
    this.lineArray;
}

View.prototype.initialize = function(){
    //Initialize stage
    this.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'tab',
    width:1200,
    height: 400
    });

    //Initialize layers
    this.backgroundLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    this.lineLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    this.noteLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    this.scanLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    this.editLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    this.UILayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    //Initialize edit layer
    this.edit = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:0,
        y:5,
        width:40,
        height:20,
        fill: 'gray',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2
    });
    this.subMeas = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:40,
        y:5,
        width:40,
        height:20,
        fill: 'blue',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2
    });
    this.addMeas = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:80,
        y:5,
        width:40,
        height:20,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2
    });
    this.addEditButtonListeners();
    this.editLayer.add(this.edit);
    this.editLayer.add(this.subMeas);
    this.editLayer.add(this.addMeas);

    //Initialize Background Layer
    this.initBackgrounds();
    this.drawBackgrounds();
    this.backgroundLayer.add(this.backgroundGroup);

    //Initialize Line Layer
    this.initLines();
    //Initialize Note Layer
    this.initNotes();

    //Add everything to the stage and display
    this.stage.add(this.backgroundLayer);
    this.stage.add(this.lineLayer);
    this.stage.add(this.noteLayer);
    this.stage.add(this.scanLayer);
    this.stage.add(this.editLayer);
    this.stage.add(this.UILayer);
}    

View.prototype.initBackgrounds = function() {
    this.backgroundGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
        x:20,
        y:80
    });
    for(var i=0; i<controller.MAX_MEASURES; i++){
        this.backgroundGroup.add(new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: i*80,
            y:0,
            width:80,
            height:220,
            fill: 'gray',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            id: i + '',
            name: i + ''
        }));    
    }
    this.drawBackgrounds();
    this.backgroundLayer.add(this.backgroundGroup);
}

View.prototype.drawBackgrounds = function() {
    var temp;
    for (var i=0; i<numMeasures; i++){
        temp = this.backgroundGroup.get('#'+i)[0];
        temp.setVisible(true);
    }
    for ( i; i<controller.MAX_MEASURES; i++){
        temp = this.backgroundGroup.get('#'+i)[0];
        temp.setVisible(false);
    }
}



View.prototype.addEditButtonListeners = function() {
    this.edit.on('click', function(){
        controller.toggleEdit();
    });
    this.subMeas.on('click', function(){
        controller.subMeasure();
    });
    this.addMeas.on('click', function(){
        controller.addMeasure();
    });
}



View.prototype.toggleEdit = function() {
    if(isEdit){
        this.subMeas.setVisible(false);
        this.addMeas.setVisible(false);
        this.stage.draw();
        isEdit = 0;
    }else {
        this.subMeas.setVisible(true);
        this.addMeas.setVisible(true);
        this.stage.draw();
        isEdit = 1;
    }
}



View.prototype.subMeasure = function() {
    var temp;
    numMeasures--;
    temp = this.backgroundGroup.get('#'+numMeasures)[0];
    temp.setVisible(false);
    this.stage.draw();
}
```

backgroundGroup is instantiated as a KineticJS group in initBackgrounds, where it gets 8 rectangles added to it, each with id 0 through 7.

The problematic get call occurs in drawBackgrounds. The non-problematic get call occurs in subMeasure.

JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/7xfLq/7/

EDIT:
I coded a workaround - I created a backgroundArray that holds the rectangles as well, and access this array in the draw backgrounds method. I don't like it though, I'd rather just keep the rectangles in the group.

Comment: Since this needs debugging, a jsfiddle might be needed

Comment: There is no code for your Model or Controller classes. Also, add the Kinetic framework in the frameworks section on the left.

Comment: Done (I haven't coded anything for model yet). Thanks for taking a look, Gerard.

Comment: you coded a workaround - meaning, you don't need any ones help anymore?

Comment: Well, I'd still like help - having both a KineticJS group and an array to hold the same rectangles is messy, it's still bugging me that I can't just use group.get().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to invoke Kinetic lookup methods before the elements were added to the stage.

If you use Chrome Developer Tools and use the "{}" button, it will pretty print the minified code, allowing you to look at the call stack to find the origin of the offending code. In this case `Stage` was not defined when you tried to do a `get()`.

JSLint is a good tool to use. It identified other problems with the code when run in JSFiddle.

This is the link for code that produces no errors.

http://jsfiddle.net/7xfLq/11/

One last thing - don't try to execute code that hasn't been coded because it will stop the execution of code for that block. Just comment out the method calls that aren't complete.

Comment: Thanks Gerard! This is my first time coding a large application, so I guess there are a lot of tools out there that I haven't heard of yet.